# I have trouble changing the size of my image on HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, image

```
<div class="profile">
  <img src="image/JaeHeadShot.jpg" alt="Head Shot"/>
  <h1> Jae Hong </h1>
</div>

.profile{
  border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  text-align:center;
  padding: 30px;
}
img.profile{
  width:423;
  height:281;
}
```

Here are my HTML and CSS. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong, but the image won't get smaller. However, if I do

```
<img src="image/JaeHeadShot.jpg" alt="headshot" width="423" height="281"/>
```

the image seems to change. I just want to know why it's not working when I work on the CSS.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

The `img.profile` wont select the image since the image doesn't have a profile class, and the numbers are missing the units.

Do it like this:

```
img {
    width  : 423px;
    height : 281px;
}
```

Comment: So how can I select the image that is in the div class "profile"? I also tried giving it an id = "headshot" and used img#headshot in CSS. It did not work. Thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: No. To use the class as a selector, you'd have to write `.profile img` to select any `img` that is a descendant of an element with the class `profile`.

Comment: To use that class name, you should do it like div.profile img {width  : 423px;
    height : 281px;}.

Comment: Since it worked for you, could you please mark the answer as correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

profile is the class for the div element, not for the image.

```
img.profile{
  width:423;
  height:281;
}
```

if you want to use special css for the image you can define a class for it.

```
.myImage{ width: 423px; height: 281px}
```

and use it in image  tag.

```
<img src="image/JaeHeadShot.jpg" alt="headshot" class=".myImage"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

The image doesn't have a class attribute in your code.So,accessing it with class profile won't fetch you image.
So,as there is only image,you can just give
`img {
 width:423;
  height:281;
}`